# Scala in Java code using Spring without Default Constructor

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc

I need to instantiate a scala class with a Spring MVC XML used in a java project. The Scala code is replacing an old java class that is actually more inefficient than it could be in scala due to certain scala frameworks and the larger amount of code required to write a fork join pool.  Is there a way to instantiate the class without using constructor parameters? How would I do this? Basically, how can I get Spring to recognize the Scala class with apparently no defined constructor?

Currently, I know I can define a class as such:

```
class MyClass(@BeanProperty var va:String){

}
```

With a constructor arg like:

```
<constructor-arg ref="va">MyValue</constructor-arg>
```

I would like to be able to write code like this:

```
class MyClass{
  @BeanProperty
  var va:String = null
}
```

I would like to use a property such as:

```
<property name="va">value</property>
```

This always yields:

```
No default constructor found
```

Is there a way to do this? So far I have tried adding @Component and even @Autowired to my class. Looking through Scala Beans, I haven't found an annotation to create a default constructor.

Comment: `class MyClass {` should result in a class with default no-arg constructor

Comment: which is the problem. A constructor seems to appear only with arguments right after the class name. I am trying to find a way to create a default constructor without insecurity, uneccesary memory; etc. Kind of like @BeanProperty generates a getter and setter.

Comment: Java classes can not have no constructor even when generated via scala. http://blog.codinsanity.be/blog/2013/08/25/scala-constructors/ should still be true

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans And how such constructor would look in java according to your standards? In Scala it's pretty standard to define such constructors, because they are being translated into those you're probably more familiar.

Comment: As I checked with my Scala 2.11, javap says that code `class MyClass { @BeanProperty var va:String = null }` generates default and **public** constructor as well

Comment: @zapl Java constructor (as well as scala) can be private but I agree that this is not an issue here

Comment: I am trying to acheive interoperability in a way that I can instantiate MyClass (a Scala class) from a Spring XML Configuration with NO CONSTRUCTOR ARGUMENTS. I have already tried def this(){ this()} which may have been comparable to a java constructor which returns an instance of a class. Please only comment or answer if you are familiar with the subject. thanks

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans "I would like to be able to write code like this" - you actually are able to write such code. `class MyClass { @BeanProperty var va:String = null }` gives you a class with, as you said, NO CONSTRUCTOR ARGUMENTS

Comment: not according to my error  :: Could not instantiate bean class [com.hygenics.parser.BreakMultipleScala]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Comment: is `new BreakMultipleScala` working without args in scala? what does `javap` show in terms of constructors when you run it on the `BreakMultipleScala.class` file? I suspect you have some leftover code or you're looking at the wrong class, have a typo or so.

Comment: it instantiates from java without arguments

Comment: for Spring 3.2.0-RELEASE + Scala 2.11.3 it works, so I'd recommend you to publish your exact project with `class MyClass { @BeanProperty var va:String = null }` on GitHub to make it more clear what's happening, otherwise we can't help

Comment: i am looking through my compiler order and checking my POM for anything I might have missed. thanks for the time

Comment: Before posting here you should start with [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (according to [SO rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: @Andrew Scott Evans and btw, please use `@dk14` to notify me about comment - otherwise I have no way to know about :). Same for other people - they gonna ignore your responses without `@nickname`

Comment: @dk14 I was really getting frustrated yesterday. I ended up having to rebuild the entire project. After that, everything seems to work. Maven was particularly useful in rebuilding but didn't really reveal any errors. The code I posted seemed to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have indicated in their comments, you should be able to just define a second no-argument constructor in Scala:

```
class MyClass(@BeanProperty var va: String) {
  def this() {
    va = null
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if Spring gets annoyed about having to choose from multiple constructors the way Guice sometimes can, but I'm guessing if you don't give it any constructor arguments it should find this default constructor in the Scala class and use it, followed by the public setter exposed by `@BeanProperty`.

I suspect that if Spring can't see the default constructor, something fishy is going on with your compiler order between Scala and Java, as others indicated.

That being said, another way you can possibly get around this is to create a static Java factory class with a static factory method that just calls the default constructor which you indicated in comments is callable from Java, just not findable from Spring. Spring should be able to find the static Java factory class and call a factory method. This is something easy to specify in Spring config. Not sure if you are so constrained that this won't work, but I wanted to share it as an alternate approach.

Comment: worse I am working on finding out why but something became corrupted and until a few runs later, I am guessing a cache?, I did not see that. I am going to fix this tomorrow and accept an answer,perhaps delete the entire thing. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up having to rebuild the entire project. For good sake, I also moved all my dependencies to Maven which isn't really a requirement but helped (especially the build process with verbosity turned on). Thanks for the help.

Comment: the secondary constructor must call the primary one, so this example doesn't compile